# Can't connect to stub

Tags: java, jsf, wsdl, stub

I am struggling with the following error:

```
05.06.2013. 17:55:43 org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isUnifiedELAvailable 
INFO: MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.
java:311)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.company.rewsapi.REWSStub.loginUser(REWSStub.java:22480)
    at com.company.rews.webclient.beans.ClientBeanBase.loginUser(ClientBeanBase.java:114)
    at com.company.rews.webclient.beans.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1015)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:284)

    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1309)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:746)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:112)
    at com.company.rews.webclient.controller.MyFacesServletWrapper.service(MyFacesServletWrapper.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
.
.
.
```

It happens on startup, first time my web service user tries to log in, first time connection to stub is tried.

Error is:

```
Remote interface error: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found.)
```

Another problem is that this is hard to debug; it happens only sometimes on first launch when launching Tomcat from Eclipse.

However, it happens all the time when web service is deployed.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it, it was a bad stub address to connect to.

Comment: @Danijiel I am facing same issue..Can you please explain the resolution little more.By bad stub address what do you mean?

Comment: Hi, it was just a wrong address, port or something really banal.